# SQL view using custom field with where

Tags: sql, view

I try to do a VIEW from a SQL Database :

```
SELECT QTE * PRICE AS TOTAL FROM produit
```

the query works fine but when i trie to use my fields "TOTAL" like this i have a problem :

```
SELECT QTE * PRICE AS TOTAL FROM produit WHERE TOTAL > 1000
```

How can i use my field TOTAL ?

Comment: You can't in every DB engine. Use `SELECT QTE * PRICE AS TOTAL FROM produit WHERE QTE * PRICE > 1000`

Answer (score 2):

Change it to this:

```
SELECT QTE * PRICE AS TOTAL FROM produit WHERE (QTE * PRICE) > 1000
```

`Total` is alias for your math operation, not column so you can't use it `where` clause

Comment: My example is simple but in my real VIEW i want to use my alias in where, case ...
So if i have to copy / paste all my math operation it will make at all of error.

Answer (score 0):

The `WHERE` clause filters the rows, and *then* the `SELECT` clause transforms them. So you can't use a transformed column in the `WHERE` clause, because effectively it doesn't exist yet.

Previous answers on repeating the expression are valid - generally that's the easy way to go. As an alternative, you could also use a derived tables - this is sometimes preferable if the calculation is complicated:

```
SELECT 
     Total 
FROM (
    SELECT QTE * PRICE AS TOTAL FROM produit
) as a
WHERE 
     Total > 1000
```